# How to disable button on click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following code is not working in IE.I need to fix this in chrome,fire fox and IE

```
 button.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
```

Comment: you do it in javaScript or on server side?

Comment: What is the generated html source code of this object?

Comment: For what? as @harry180 said it shell be better to make it with js

Answer (score 6):

You just have to set it's [`Enabled` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled) to `false` on serverside:

```
button.Enabled = false;
```

Edit: If `button` is a link and it doesn't work in other browsers than IE, have a look at following link: http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2009/05/how-to-enable-or-disable-linkbutton-in.html

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTest" runat="server" CommandArgument="1" CommandName="1x"
OnClick="lnkTest_Click">Test</asp:LinkButton>
```

Style for enabling and Disabling is

```
<style>
.LnkEnabled
{
cursor: pointer;
}
.LnkDisabled
{
cursor: default;
color: Gray;
}
</style>
```

javascript function

```
<script language="javascript">
function EnableLinkButton(ID,flag)
{
   document.getElementById(ID).onclick=function(){return flag;};
   if(!flag)
   { 
      document.getElementById(ID).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
      document.getElementById(ID).className="LnkDisabled";
   }
   else
   {
      document.getElementById(ID).setAttribute("disabled","");
      document.getElementById(ID).className="LnkEnabled";
   }
}
EnableLinkButton('<%= lnkTest.ClientID %>',false);
</script>
```

**Edit2**: If that doesn't work (haven't tested it), you could also try this:

```
button.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return !this.disabled;")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 button.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
```

Comment: Ohk..try now..I have made some changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button_id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Is the same as what `Enabled=false` on serverside generates or `Attributes["disabled"]="disabled"` does. But it apparently doesn't work for other browsers than IE with links (anchor tags): `<a href="#" id="button" disabled="disabled">this is not disabled in FF</a>`